# Can I use a 3 Gbit/s SATA hard drive with a 6 Gbit/s SATA port?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, computer-building

As you may have heard, Intel identified an issue with the [P67 chipset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#Core_i_Series_chipsets) in a recent press release which caused a loss of data over time with the 3 Gbit/s SATA ports. I recently built a Sandy Bridge PC with a 3 Gbit/s [hard drive.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822152181)

I'm pretty ticked, but they said using only the 6 Gbit/s slots is a valid workaround. Would this be all right? What about with [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827135204) DVD drive?

Comment: Btw I totally feel your pain, took me 8 hours to get my watercooling installed only to hear my motherboard might be flawed? :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they're perfectly backwards compatible.

[To quote Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA)

> Also, the new standard is backwards compatible with SATA 3 Gbit/s. [[14]](http://www.sata-io.org/developers/naming_guidelines.asp)

Given that SATA is a standard interface, it doesn't matter whether it's a hard drive or disk drive, it should work with every SATA compatible device.

But off course you won't get more performance if the drive itself doesn't allow anything above 3 Gb/s. However, if you have any (fast) SSDs it would actually be a good idea to plug them into those ports.

If you don't feel like replacing the motherboard and have some room left in your case, you could get a PCI SATA adapter, that way you can avoid using the potentially flawed SATA 3 ports entirely

Comment: Sweet!  I don't think I want to spend the money on a SATA adapter, though, as the company I bought the mobo from said they're extending the return deadline to whenever Intel releases the fixed versions, so I should be able to replace it for the cost of shipping.  Still inconvenient...but whatever.  Regardless, that's some sage advice.  Thanks again, @Ivo!